# Moviepy: Resize image with black borders

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I have a problem with resizing videos in moviepy. When I use the `clip.resize(1920,1080)` function, it stretches the image. I want it to stretch the image, keep the aspect ratio, but add black borders to it (to fill the aspect ratio).

[This is the source image/video (resolution: 670 x 844)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DnXY.jpg)

[This is how I want it to look (resolution: 1920 x 1080)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XKs4.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Mix it with some black image in resolution you whish:

```
video = mp.VideoFileClip("/media/pi/video.mp4")
black_image = (mp.ImageClip("black_picture_1920x1080.jpg"))
mp.CompositeVideoClip([black_image, video.set_position("center")])
```

Comment: Just to add to @user5214530s answer you might want to resize the original clip to the desired height before overlaying the imagelike so  video = mp.VideoFileClip("/media/pi/video.mp4").resize(height=1080)

Comment: black_image = ImageClip("black.jpg", duration=59)